# arrow function returning an object

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions

I returned to new JS after a decade and trying to learn new syntax.

I don't know what is wrong with syntax:

```
const images = this.props.update.imageUrls.map(imageUrl =>  
    {original:imageUrl,thumbnail:imageUrl} );
```

It keeps giving error:

```
UpdateView.js: Unexpected token, expected ; (41:96)
      > 41 |         const images = this.props.update.imageUrls.map(imageUrl =>  {original:imageUrl,thumbnail:imageUrl} );
           |                                                                                                 ^
```

This old syntax works and does what I want:

```
const images = this.props.update.imageUrls.map(function(imageUrl,index) {
    return {"original":imageUrl,"thumbnail":imageUrl}} );
```

Comment: Wrap the object in `()` to return as object. `imageUrl => ({original:imageUrl,thumbnail:imageUrl})`

Comment: Possible Dup of [ECMAScript6 arrow function that returns an object](//stackoverflow.com/q/28770415)